# Getting exception on locking the key redis-lock nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

When trying to lock the hashkey  as follow getting an exception:

**I am referring the following docs:**

https://redis.io/topics/distlock

https://github.com/mike-marcacci/node-redlock

```
var redis = require('redis');
var Redlock = require('redlock');
var redisClient = redis.createClient(settings.redisport, settings.redishost);
var redlock = new Redlock(
// you should have one client for each independent redis node
// or cluster
[redisClient],
{
    // the expected clock drift; for more details
    // see http://redis.io/topics/distlock
    driftFactor: 0.01, // time in ms

    // the max number of times Redlock will attempt
    // to lock a resource before erroring
    retryCount: 10,

    // the time in ms between attempts
    retryDelay: 200, // time in ms

    // the max time in ms randomly added to retries
    // to improve performance under high contention
    // see https://www.awsarchitectureblog.com/2015/03/backoff.html
    retryJitter: 200 // time in ms
 }
);

redlock.lock([Key], settings.lockttl).then(function (lock) {
    return lock.unlock();
}).catch(function (err) {

    return lock.unlock();
});


ERR Error running script (call to f_cf0e94b2e9ffc7e04395cf88f7583fc309985910): @user_script:1: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
Exceeded 10 attempts to lock the resource "Room:1111".
Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: lock is not defined
    at app.js:559:17
    at tryCatcher (bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
```

Please suggest what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, It was my mistake. I missed to prefix **'locks:'** to the key.

If anyone struggling with issue, then can refer this, by the way in the documentation it has not been mentioned about prefix **'locks:'** to key.

Comment: It's not necessary to prefix the key with `locks:`; I've used it without any prefix with no issues. Another thing that can lead to un-explained lock acquisition failures is if you've changed the drift factor from the default of 0.01ms.  `driftFactor: 0.01 // time in ms`